# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached skipping layout

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with `RecyclerView` in a `Fragment`. In `MainActivity` I have a `TabLayout` and a `ViewPager`. I want to show the `RecyclerView` in my first tab but I keep getting the following error:

> E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

I have tried to move the recycler adapter initialization to `OnViewCreated` but to no result.

Here is my fragment code:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        listOfGreetings?.add(0, GreetingModel("Greeting 1", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background))
        listOfGreetings?.add(1, GreetingModel("Greeting 2", R.drawable.greeting_1))
        listOfGreetings?.add(2, GreetingModel("Greeting 3", R.drawable.greeting_1))
        listOfGreetings?.add(3, GreetingModel("Greeting 4", R.drawable.greeting_1))
        listOfGreetings?.add(4, GreetingModel("Greeting 5", R.drawable.greeting_1))
        listOfGreetings?.add(5, GreetingModel("Greeting 6", R.drawable.greeting_1))
        listOfGreetings?.add(6, GreetingModel("Greeting 7", R.drawable.greeting_1))
        listOfGreetings?.add(7, GreetingModel("Greeting 8", R.drawable.greeting_1))


        val recyclerView = container?.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
        val manager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)



        recyclerView?.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView?.layoutManager = manager



        recyclerView?.adapter = greetingAdapter

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false)

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        greetingAdapter = GreetingAdapter(activity!!, listOfGreetings!!.toList())
    }
```

Here is the XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             tools:context=".CategoryFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Does it still give error when using `onViewCreated()` and using `view.findViewById()`?

Comment: Use onViewCreated() to inflate your views that depend upon your root view.

Comment: @TaseerAhmad yes. it still give error, no result((

Comment: @MartinMarconcini   I have moved my recycler view initialization on 
      onViewCreated but it didn't help(

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
        val manager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)



        recyclerView?.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView?.layoutManager = manager
  recyclerView?.adapter = greetingAdapter
        greetingAdapter = GreetingAdapter(activity!!, listOfGreetings!!.toList())
    }

Comment: The error is telling you that your RecyclerView, *at the time of the layout pass*, did not have an adapter (yet), so its layout pass is going to be skipped (because a RecyclerView without an adapter is basically useless); try moving the `recyclerView?.adapter = greetingAdapter` line right below where you obtain the reference. Also post your adapter, it's hard to tell if the adapter is working fine if we cannot see it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing this error message because the safe call `?.` in `recyclerView?.adapter = greetingAdapter` will return null so it won't get executed because you're calling it before the view gets inflated which is `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false)`.

To solve that simply, create a variable that has the value of the inflated view, then use it to get a view from it:

```kotlin
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {


listOfGreetings?.add(0, GreetingModel("Greeting 1", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background))
        listOfGreetings?.add(1, GreetingModel("Greeting 2", R.drawable.greeting_1))
        listOfGreetings?.add(2, GreetingModel("Greeting 3", R.drawable.greeting_1))
        listOfGreetings?.add(3, GreetingModel("Greeting 4", R.drawable.greeting_1))
        listOfGreetings?.add(4, GreetingModel("Greeting 5", R.drawable.greeting_1))
        listOfGreetings?.add(5, GreetingModel("Greeting 6", R.drawable.greeting_1))
        listOfGreetings?.add(6, GreetingModel("Greeting 7", R.drawable.greeting_1))
        listOfGreetings?.add(7, GreetingModel("Greeting 8", R.drawable.greeting_1))


 //This variable will hold a reference to the inflated view.
 val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false)

 //Get the recyclerView from the inflated view.
 val recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
 val manager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

 //No need for the safe call ?. here because recyclerView won't be null. 
 recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
 recyclerView.layoutManager = manager
 recyclerView.adapter = greetingAdapter

 return view 
}
```

Also, you're overusing the safe call operator `?.` in your code. `listGreetings` can be made much simpler, you can use `apply()` on an object which is `listGreeting` in our case with the safe call:

```kotlin
listOfGreetings?.apply {
            add(0, GreetingModel("Greeting 1", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background))
            add(1, GreetingModel("Greeting 2", R.drawable.greeting_1))
            add(2, GreetingModel("Greeting 3", R.drawable.greeting_1))
            add(3, GreetingModel("Greeting 4", R.drawable.greeting_1))
            add(4, GreetingModel("Greeting 5", R.drawable.greeting_1))
            add(5, GreetingModel("Greeting 6", R.drawable.greeting_1))
            add(6, GreetingModel("Greeting 7", R.drawable.greeting_1))
            add(7, GreetingModel("Greeting 8", R.drawable.greeting_1))
 }
```

This will check that if `listGreetings` not equals null the will execuate the code in the `apply` block:

```
apply{
//block
}
```

Comment: Also, note that kotlin provides an easier way to get certain view from the inflated layout, so you can do the following `view.recyclerView` directly without the needs to call `view.findViewById()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot:) Your code works) Only I moved 
 greetingAdapter = GreetingAdapter(activity!!, listOfGreetings!!.toList())
on onCreatedView metod

Comment: I want to accept the answer, but unfortunately my reputation less than 15 ((  I am new in stackoverfloow. Thanks for help:)